# Show certain property of a greatest common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $\gcd(r,s)=\gcd(r',s')=1$. How do I show that also $\gcd(rs'+r's,ss')=1$?

Comment: You don't.  Suppose $s=s'=2$, say.  With $r,r'$ odd, of course.

Comment: Hmm you are right. Strange. I have to use it for an exercise.

Comment: You can additionally impose $(s,s') = 1$. This suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. Let $r=r'=3$ and $s=s'=2$. Then you have
$$\gcd(rs'+r's,ss')=\gcd(3\cdot2+3\cdot 2,2\cdot2)=\gcd(12,4)=4$$